# Gitkraken can not access pull requests on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request

I experience an issue when i try to fetch my project. It tells me that it could not access my pull requests on gitlab. This is the only project i have this issue. Others work just fine using the same account on GitLab. I have already googled that topic but i only find topics that are outdated and do not point to a solution.

The text says:

> Could not get pull requests for [myProjectURL] on GitLab. Double-check your remote urls and make sure you have permission to access that repository.

I see that whenever i try to fetch or pull. Pushing new Code works just fine, even creating a new Branche works out.

What i have tried:

- looked into my preferences/Applications --> Gitkraken is listed.
- tried to removed the local repository and cloned it again using Gitkraken.
  --> But the Error persists.

I would be thanksful for ideas to solve this issue.

Comment: Good question Rolf!

Answer (score 0):

After a crash of my Gitkraken application today the issue is gone.
So i guess this was kind of a bug inside of GitKraken.

But in case someone has a clue what might had gone wrong here i would appreciate it.